# Run a Program Without User Being Logged On

Tags: windows-7, service, logon-scripts, autorun

I am running a Windows 7 installation, and I want to be able to run an application when there is no user logged in. The reason for this is that my application is a monitoring tool, and we want to be able to monitor 24/7 even if the computer reboots. From what I've gathered on the net, there are two ways of doing this:

1. Create a service and run it under an Administrator account
2. Use windows group policies to set up a logon script:
   This is where things get a bit unclear, as people seem to confuse running a program in the background without a user logged in with running a program *just* after user has logged in. If I setup my program to run in this mode, will it run *if no one logs in*?

Can you comment on either #1, #2, which one you would recommend and why? Maybe there is another way I do not know about?

Thank you for the help,

Comment: Services are more preferred way to run programs regardless of whether user is logged in or not, however you can also run a task using task scheduler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run a program when no one is logged in, by using the Windows Task Scheduler. However, if your application needs to interact with a user, it may not work exactly how you'd like.

Check out the On Startup Trigger for more info (might be under Advanced config of a new task).

More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a service which you can do from any .exe with [this method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890).

This will make your program run on startup without having to login. If you subsequently need to interact with the program you can connect to the [console session](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278845).